# Carbonite backup - local cache?

Tags: backup, online-storage, carbonite

Im using a Windows 08R2 Server I have running 24/7 which I use as a file server amongst other things and connect to it from my laptop.

I have tried out a number of online backups (dropbox,soapbox,humyo) only to be let down because they all cache the files you wish to backup in their own local application folder, obviously if you point your backup at a 50GB backup folder and it tries to copy it all to the cache on the same drive, well...its bad.

I have recently installed Carbonite on my server and its application (Info Centre) it seems superb. The main feature I wanted was to say backup only between certain hours, which Carbonite provides as my ISP gives me free bandwith between 12 and 8am (doesnt count towards my usage).

The thing I would like to know and the point of this post is: Does the carbonite app cache locally? in its C:\Prog Fil..Carbonite there is only an EXE and a DLL. I cannot even find a file e.g INI which records my specific settings. There is nothing under C:\Users\App Data either.

Where does it store local settings information, e.g there must be a file somewhere listing all the locally pending/backed up files even so it can provide the overlay icons on them.

If it doesnt cache locally then im sold. Just want to be sure, so it wont clog up my drive by copying large folders.

Thanks.

Comment: I found it, in SQL 08R2 its in C:\Program Data. It seems to be that it only copies the file its currently uploading, rather than ALL the files pending upload into its "Program Data" directory. If that is the case, thats fine as it should never grow that big.